# Is there a good way to test parent classes in Ruby?

Tags: inheritance, rspec

I have a class that will be inherited from in Ruby. Is there a good way to test this class in Rspec? Would you create child classes in the test and have them inherit from the parent to see if the children have the appropriate methods? For example:

Say this is our parent class:

```
class Animal
    def breathe
        "it's breathing"
    end

    def self.color(some_color)
        @color = some_color
    end

    attr_reader :color
end
```

and in our test

```
let(:dummy_animal) do
   class DummyAnimal < described_class
      color :brown
    end

    DummyAnimal
end
```

However, the above doesn't work. The returned `DummyAnimal` doesn't have any instance variables set which is what I was expecting. Is there a good way to test this? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? I don't think it matter that you'll be inheriting from other classes - that is other classes problem so other classes specs.

Answer (score 1):

> Would you create child classes in the test and have them inherit from the parent to see if the children have the appropriate methods?

No. Test the code that *you* write. Inheritance is a basic feature of Ruby classes, let the authors of Ruby ensure that it works. Same goes for external libraries, gems, and other third-party code.

If you are inheriting one class from another, or mixing in code from modules, each unit (class or module) should have its own tests. When one class extends the behavior of another you should only test the new features that are added or overridden.

Comment: But then how do I test the parent class?

Comment: Write a separate test for the parent class. E.g., in your example the method `:breathe` is defined in Animal, so the unit tests for Animal should test that method. Animal's unit test should also cover `:color`. If a child class overrides `:color`, it should have a unit test for its own behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me to create classes in the specs.

I would have the classes defined in the app code:

```
class DummyAnimal < Animal
  ...
end
```

In the specs

```
describe DummyAnimal
  specify '#color' do
    expect(subject.color).to eq 'brown'
  end
end
```